# Injective of vectoric function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have the function $$f(x,y)=(x+y,xy)\quad U=[{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} |\quad 0 <y<x}] $$

I am trying to show that $f$ is global invertebility in $U$.

to do that I though on showing that $f$ is injective function in $U$ but I am not sure how to do that with the inequality I given in the set $U$

Comment: Why not start by trying to construct an inverse? If $a = x+y, b = xy$, can you find equations for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$ and $b$? Once you do, note that $0 < y < x$ helps you make the formula unique.

Comment: I tried to do your suggestion but I have no idea how I suppose to procced from there.

Comment: Were you able to find equations for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$ and $b$? What were they?

Comment: Yes, I got that $x=a-y \quad y=\frac{b}{x}$ I am not sure how I can build the formula from here, in addition how I use it to show that $f$ is injection function

Comment: No that's not enough, plug that equation for $y$ into $x$ so you can get an equation for $x$ purely in terms of $a$ and $b$ and similarly for $y$. Then you have shown that this function has an inverse, which in turn implies the function is injective. Considering you're trying to show $f$ is invertible on $U$, showing the actual inverse is definitely the most direct way to do it.

Comment: I am sorry but I still not understand what you mean to, after doing your last suggestion I got $x=a-\frac{b}{x} \quad y=\frac {b}{a-y}$ how I should procced from here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107924/discussion-between-sagigever-and-osama-ghani).